# How can one determine their body's Omega Fatty Acid balance?

Tags: diet, supplements

I just read a [great article](http://theconsciouslife.com/anti-inflammatory-diet-how-to-balance-omega-3-omega-6-fats.htm) on internal inflammation and Omega-3/Omega-6 levels.  It states they should be closer to 1-to-1 than the typical 15-1 ratio of modern diets.

I'm willing to supplement Omega 3, and have already changed my diet to reduce Omega 6, but I'm not clear on what proper total levels are and how to test for them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there aren't any readily available standard tests, as I don't believe they have established any guideline levels for blood yet. You can get home kits such as [this one](http://www.genesmart.com/pages/omega_3_index_home_blood_testing_kit/105.php) and get your levels, but it's really kind of an academic number.

The blood tests for porphyria (some people call it the "vampire" test) include an ALA level, but that's the only clinical one I'm aware of that tests for any of the Omega 3 fatty acids.

Also, be careful about suddenly just ingesting tons of Omega-3's, somewhere in the early 2000's the FDA published warnings of health risks associated with large quantity Omega-3 supplementation.

Part of the problem is that they just aren't really understood yet, so while they know that Omega-3s are beneficial and that the ratio is important, they haven't really established WHY they are important or what good levels are, that kind of thing.

Comment: I was looking at the test you mention.  It appears to test more than simple ALA levels given all the things they talk about.  Just marketing fluff?